# Finding the magnitude of Two Vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

Vector C has a magnitude 23.4 m and is in the direction of the negative y-axis. Vectors A and B are at angles α = 44.4° and β = 27.7° up from the x-axis respectively. If the vector sum A+B+C = 0, what are the magnitudes of A and B?

Using logic I've figured out some stuff: 
since A+B+C = 0 then Ax+Bx+0 = 0 (since Cx = 0) and Ay+By-23.4 = 0. 
Ax and Bx must be equal with opposite signs.
Ay and By have a sum of positive 23.4.
Since A is in quadrant 1 both Ax and Ay are positive, 
and B is in Quadrant 2 so Bx is negative and By is positive.

I don't exactly know what to do now... Fairly sure it's something to do with the two angles I haven't used yet but... I have no idea...

Edit: Using Lami's Theorem I got the answers of A = 21.9 and B = 17.5, which are the correct answers.

[image: Picture of the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw figures of the vector in a paper and then use resolution of vectors using the angles you have got. And you will get the solution, by making sum of components of vectors in x and   y- direction  zero.

Or  better: use [Lami's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lami%27s_theorem) [theorem](http://www.tutorvista.com/content/physics/physics-iii/motion-laws/lamis-theorem.php).

Comment: +1 for [Lami's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lami%27s_theorem); somehow I hadn't encountered that particular rule.

Comment: You're welcome @user3564967

Answer (score 1):

In general the vector equation 
$$\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{C}=0 $$
means
$$A_x+B_x+C_x=0,\quad A_y+B_y+C_y=0 $$
or in terms of your angles and magnitudes of the vectors
$$A \cos\alpha+B \cos\beta=0,\quad A\sin\alpha+B\sin\beta-C=0 $$
since $C$ is along a negative $y$. You know $\alpha,\beta, C$ so you can solve for $A$ and $B$.